# Как Исправить функцию click

Tags: jquery

добрий день 
надо написать предупреждения про переход на другую страницу на мобильной версии при клике
есть функция на jquery при клик

```
if('html').css({maxWidth: '800px'})
```

$( "#carouselExampleIndicator" ).click(function() {
    alert('you definitely want to go to another page'
)
    })

не могу понять где ошибка зарание спс

Comment: Что за бред вы написали здесь? If() подразумевается проверка, `{maxWidth: '800px'}` фигурные скобки говорят о том что вы не получаете значение `maxWidth` а устанавливаете, проверить когда установить значение, wtf?

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам надо, чтобы алерт выскакивал только при разрешении экрана до 800px, то это можно сделать так:

```js
let link = document.getElementById('link');

link.onclick = function() {
   if(window.matchMedia('(max-width: 800px)').matches) {
     alert('Точно перейти?');
   }
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.ru" id="link">Ссылка</a>
```

А если Вам надо, чтобы в принципе ссылка была видна только на экранах до 800px, то можно использовать медиа-запрос:

```js
let link = document.getElementById('link');

link.onclick = function() {
     alert('Точно перейти?');
}
```

```css
#link {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #link {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.ru" id="link">Ссылка</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример обычного перехода по ссылке, где пользователь, прежде должен подтвердить действие. Вам просто нужно добавить условие внутри события клик на проверку мобильного устройства.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (confirm('You definitely want to go to another page?')) {
    location.href = $(this).attr('href');
  }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://yandex.ru">Уйти со Stackoverflow навсегда в поиск</a>
```

Comment: да но при отмене  тебя не возвращаеть назад на страницу а всеровно переход по силке

Comment: @МішаКорольков как это? В диалоговом окне вы нажимаете да и переходите по ссылке либо нет и остаетесь там где были, может вы используете устаревшую версию браузера что у вас другое поведение?

Comment: спс ви помогли проблема била в тому что я подключал jqveri <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> ,без ajax , спс ви очень помогли !!!

Comment: @МішаКорольков рад был помочь, если что, обращайтесь ;-)